MediaPlayer throws a MediaException only in the JAR File
I build a litte Audio Player in Java 11 and JavaFX for Windows.
Right now I have only a demo. After that i wrote it in my IDE (Intellj Idea), I decide to build the JAR file to make sure it was right.
Inside the IDE the the demo is perfect, but if I try to use the JAR file it won't open.
Only using the Windows CMD i get some error
"C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jre-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar  "Demo-jar.jar"
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/[path]/demo_jar/demo-jar%202.jar!/com/example/demo/primary.fxml

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.demo.App.loadFXML(App.java:31)
        at com.example.demo.App.start(App.java:20)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.demo.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:35)
        ... 14 more

I don't know why in the IDE works, and in the JAR file not.
This is the code that throws Exception
public AudioPlayer(String audioFolderPath) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File(audioFolderPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (!dir.mkdir())
            throw new Exception("Impossibile creare la cartella Sound");
    }

    this.songsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    this.songsArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));

    if (!this.songsArray.isEmpty()) {
        this.media = new Media(songsArray.get(0).toURI().toString());
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    } else {
        this.media = null;
        this.mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}


For the needs of the App, i can't include the Audio file (.mp3) inside the JAR file.
Someone have some ideas?
Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad English
All the files exist, they can be read and execute.
I've seen another post, still on StackOverflow, about this topic. They said how on Ubutu the way i create the Media is wrong, so i tried also
            this.media = new Media("file:/C:/Sound/Campanello_Casa.mp3");


but nothing change.

"i can't include the Audio file (.mp3) inside the JAR file" Why not? If the audio file is not in the jar file, where will it be located when you deploy the application?

"This is the code that throws Exception" That's not the code throwing the exception in the stack trace. That exception is thrown from the initialize() method in your Controller class.

"They said how on Ubutu the way i create the Media is wrong, so i tried also this.media = new Media("file:/C:/Sound/Campanello_Casa.mp3");". There is no C: drive on Ubuntu.

I will answer to all three comments, thanks for reading. I can't include Audio files inside the JAR file due to the project specifics. They say "Audio files must be in a folder named Sound". I know that the Exception has been thrown by the initialize()  method, but it just call this constructor. If you want I can add that to the Post. At Lest, i know that Ubuntu (like all the Linux Distro) doesn't have a C: drive, but i adapt the path to my Windows PC.
If there would be another question, just ask me

FWIW here is a very old media player I wrote.  That example wraps the JavaFX media player in Swing because that is what the question asked, but you don't have to (should not) do that.

Take a Look at your stacktrace: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException         at com.example.demo.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:35)
